# I am new to Kotlin language. Can anyone help how to add two total value that is displayed on different onClickListener?

Tags: kotlin

```
var addQuantity = 0     // counter variable

 // button_two on clickListener 
button_two.setOnClickListener{                                     
    val laptopTwo = 500.60
    val total_price_two: Double
    addQuantity = addQuantity + 1
    total_price_two = (addQuantity * laptopTwo).toDouble()
    resultDisplayText.text = total_price_two.toString()       //displays the result in TextView
}

 // button_three on clickListener 
button_three.setOnClickListener {
    val laptopThree=400.00
    val total_price_three:Double
    addQuantity = addQuantity + 1
    total_price_three =( addQuantity * laptopThree).toDouble()
    resultDisplayText.text=total_price_three.toString() //displays the result in TextView 
}

//submit button on clickListener
submit.setOnClickListener {                                              
    val total: Double
    total = total_price_three + total_price_two // get an error here....
}
```

Each time I clicked on `button_two` and `button_three`, it increase the quantity and give total price for the quantities . Now I want to display the total price when click on submit button, but it's not working. Can anyone help me fix this issue.

Comment: Please spend an extra bit of time and format the code in your question as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). As is, it's very hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit` button doesn't have access to `total_price_two` and `total_price_three` since they are *locally scoped* to the click listeners for the two buttons. If you pull them into the outer scope, they will be accessible:

```
var addQuantity = 0     // counter variable
var total_price_two: Double = 0.0
var total_price_three: Double = 0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help though I already solved it.